# is there any way to automate javascript errors thrown in firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-rc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [capturing javascript error in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189312/capturing-javascript-error-in-selenium)

can we capture/automate the js errors thrown in browser while clicking the page .Is it possible to capture with selenium (as far my knowledge i think no!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'll repost it here again. You can do it by handling `window.onerror` event. See the following link http://www.silverwareconsulting.com/index.cfm/2010/6/7/Checking-for-JavaScript-Errors-with-Selenium. But anyway, this question is possibly duplicate with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189312/capturing-javascript-error-in-selenium).

Answer (score 1):

You can detect JavaScript error using Selenium. Following blog will be great help to you http://incodewetrustinc.blogspot.com/2008/06/detecting-javascript-errors-with.html

Comment: but we have to add that script in product code or can we have it in some other way.