# Check for Javascript errors with Selenium/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing automated test for a specific application, I'd need to check for Javascript errors in Chrome if possible with Selenium. Is there any already in-built class for this or any other handy way of doing this?

Comment: A nice solution has been given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189312/capturing-javascript-error-in-selenium

Comment: @ptrk I'd have to inject a script to the page in this case, I'd rather be checking for js errors without any dependency on the page itself if possible.

Comment: Selenium is actually js injected into the page anyway, but I understand you don't want the original page modified. Then perhaps this link would be helpful: http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/09/capturing-javascript-errors-in.html