# How to get Console Output of URL in python?

Tags: python, url, console, output

I searched for a solution to my problem but couldnt find any.

Is there a way to open a URL in python and get the console output from that url?

Im trying to check a list of URLs for Javascript errors.
The only solution I found was using Selenium but its incredible slow.

Comment: The console output of chrome/firefox/ie - which browser ?

Comment: Chrome or firefox mainly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For chrome errors you might find the node module of [LightHouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/?utm_source=mailinglist&utm_medium=reply&utm_campaign=2018Q1#cli) suiting your needs.
- For Firefox there is [Browser_Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console).

From first look the Chrome solution seems easier.

- Last but not least I stumbled over the python module [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) which can do liveserver testing.

For reference see this [django use case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase), there is also an [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189312/capturing-javascript-error-in-selenium) how to catch js errors