# How to automatically test application web page looking for error?

Tags: selenium, testing, web

Is there an easy way to test some web page looking for some errors. I mean usually while doing web testing we want to check the display which could be very difficult to maintain.
So I wanted to know if as an alternative strategy there are some practice to massively test the URLs of a website and just look for any kind of error including JS error in the console.
I think it is possible using a framework like Selenium but it might be a bit overkill no ?
Also the idea will be to do that on a production server, in addition to test server.

The website have some authentication so just hitting the URLs will not work.

Comment: It'll depend on how the site returns errors.  Some won't return the standard error codes.  Best to just keep a log server-side.  For client-side console errors you might be able to use Selenium.  I found some older 3.x solutions here using getLogs (which I think is still marked as beta): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189312/capturing-javascript-error-in-selenium   I think Selenium 4 should have more support for this in BiDi API: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidi_apis/

Comment: Btw, if the site does return standard 404s, there's a tool I used to use a lot called Xenu's Link Sleuth.  It'll just crawl the whole site and report any 404s found.  (It's pretty old now, so I bet there's some better tools like that out there...)

Comment: Google Analytics is also a good option it'll keep a log of all errors.